# How can I display a query in a page?

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, query, mysql

I'm new with Wordpress development and I trying to display a query result from the wp_postmeta table.

Does anyone know how to that? Do I have to connect with the MySQL with `mysql_connect()` or does WP have a built-in function for that?

Thanks!

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Hang on - are you trying to display the actual query or just the results of a post meta search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$wpdb` object

```
// Print last SQL query string
$wpdb->last_query
```

or:

```
<?php
  if (current_user_can('administrator')){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wpdb->queries);
    echo "</pre>";
  }//Lists all the queries executed on your page
?>
```

You might have to set `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);` in `wp-config.php`